# Handling batch requests with jax-rs

Tags: java, json, api, request, jax-rs

The problem I am trying to solve is to handle batch requests on the server. I am using JAX-RS Apache cxf on Mac using JSON for serialization. I did some research and found that batch requests can be implemented in a couple of ways on the server.

1. All the requests in the batch are similar eg., PUT for ids 1 to 100.
2. All the requests in the batch are different eg, a couple of them might be PUT, POST, GET...

I analyzed the requirements again and realized I need to implement the second. I broke down the problem to three parts: consuming batch request, reconstructing individual requests on the server, and dispatching them to respective URIs.

I have a POST method 'handleBatchRequest' in my API layer (Path : /batch) and I subclassed HttpRequest. The method 'handleBatchRequest' consumes List of individual requests. The first part works.

I am stuck at the second part and I cannot find a way to dispatch the request to the respective URIs from the server. I do not want to bypass the API layer and send them directly to the inner layer.

If anyone has come across a similar problem before, any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why not to use jaxrs-client in order to send requests to worker urls?

Comment: I tried using this, but looks like the problem is that the cxf client factory gives access to the API resource itself. I could not find a way to create a subresource, where the request URI has a query/path parameter, unless I parse the URI and extract the parameters out, which I think would be not good in this case.